# Lightbox with Pagination

Tags: pagination, lightbox

I'm searching for a jQuery lightbox that includes a pagination below the image in the Lightbox itself to switch to specific images, without cycling through them all with standard arrows.

Example:
<<  <  5 6 7 8 9  >  >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see following link for lightbox jquery with pagination

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts